# WebApi - Post incorrect Time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Im posting data(model) to an api service, the time is correct when sending, but the receiving api subtracts 1 hour, why does this happen and how do I resolve this?

Preparing to send the request:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult RequestBooking(string model)
{

    var e = new BookingRequest();
    var objJavascript = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    e = objJavascript.Deserialize<BookingRequest>(model);
    //e.AppointmentDate = 21/09/2016 13:00:00
    string addressRoute = "api.domain.com/Booking/Post";
    using (var booking = new HttpClient())
    {
        booking.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        var response = booking.PostAsync(addressRoute, new StringContent(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(e), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
        return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

On the receiving:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostRequest(DomainObjects.BookingRequest request)
{
     //request.Appointment = 21/09/2016 12:00:00 <----
}
```

Comment: Probably due to time zone differences but I am just guessing as you never posted the actual string representation of the time being sent to the server. When using client/server architecture (web api included) you should always send your datetime instances using [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format and as UTC OR with an offset specified in the instance (.net type = DateTimeOffset)..

Comment: Side note: could you please format your code properly when posting?

Comment: Sorry, the unix timestap being sent (to the receiver) 1474459200000, how do i convert to ISO8601 as this is doing it new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(e)?

Comment: Does that really matter? Not as far as I can tell from the bit you posted: `//e.AppointmentDate = 21/09/2016 13:00:00` <= you are leading us to believe your model probably contains a `System.DateTime` instance with that value and this is what is being received on the Web API as `21/09/2016 12:00:00`. If this is not correct then you need to update your code example with the model, what is being sent (what is the serialized value that is being sent to the web api), and what is the type that deserializes that value.

Comment: I mention it to confirm the conversion is happening on the send.Correct, AppointmentDate is a type of DateTime

Comment: Use datatime2 as your date member type.